# Angular scope; a special case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's consider a very simple code:

```
<div id="main" ng-app='myapp' ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
  <div>
    Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="qty">
  </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome's console:

```
var x=angular.element('#main').scope();
```

returns:

```
Scope {$id: 1, $$childTail: ChildScope, $$childHead: ChildScope, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null…}
```

*My question*: **In what way the above Scope object is accessible through the console**? What do I have to write to the right side as the comparison returns true?

```
x.__proto__===*.Scope.prototype
```

since `x.__proto__ returns Scope{}` . Where this **Scope** object lives?

Answer (score 3):

The `Scope` constructor/function is intentionally not exposed to the console. It is defined inside an IIFE deep within the angular library - specifically within the `$RootScopeProvider` function. All you need to know is that you can create new scopes using the `$new()` method of the scope object - you do not need to access this constructor method directly.